# Weird things happen when installing eric5-5.3.8 for Python 3.3.2

Tags: python

I've already installed python 3.3.2 and PyQt4-4.10.3-gpl-Py3.3-Qt5.1.0-x32.exe.

I think the problem can be stated like this:the `install.py` of `eric5-5.3.8` thinks there is no module named `PyQt4.QtWebKit` (even the python shell thinks so).

```
>>> import PyQt4.QtSvg
>>> import PyQt4.QtWebKit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import PyQt4.QtWebKit
ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。
```

But the file **PyQt4.QtWebKit** does exist! Just like **PyQt4.QtSvg**!

this is the proof:
[image]

the related code in install.py is:

```
for impModule in [
    "PyQt4.QtGui", "PyQt4.QtNetwork", "PyQt4.QtSql",
    "PyQt4.QtSvg", "PyQt4.QtWebKit",
]:
    name = impModule.split(".")[1]
    modulesOK = True
    try:
        __import__(impModule)
        print("Found", name)
    except ImportError as msg:
        print('Sorry, please install {0}.'.format(name))
        print('Error: {0}'.format(msg))
        modulesOK = False
```

I spent almost my whole day trying to solve this problem but it was all in vain.
How can I solve this problem to install eric5-5.3.8 for Python 3.3.2?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error says "DLL load failed". That means that the DLL used in creating the `QtWebKit` module can't be found when the module is imported. So, the module is fine, however, it requires a DLL that you either don't have, or for which your path is set incorrectly. Please check the requirement for Qt or QtWebKit explicitly, to see which binaries (DLLs) are needed, and make sure those are available.

Comment: @Evert I've also installed Qt 5.1.1 and there are several dictionaries named `QtWebKit` in it. Such as `C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2010_opengl\imports\QtWebKit`.

Comment: Those directory names say `Qt5`, while your Python package is `Qt4`. I don't really know, but generally, across major versions, binaries are incompatible. You may want to think about upgrading `PyQt`. Note that the installation documentation says you would need to install `PyQt5` from source, as binary installations of `PyQt4` and `PyQt5` together are not possible. Or remove `PyQt4` altogether first. Do check the requirements for `eric5` first though: you may need to downgrade `Qt` itself to version 4!

Comment: @Evert thanks. problem is `solved` when I choose python 3.2.5 and PyQt-Py3.2-x86-gpl-4.9.6-1.exe. Maybe developers of python and eric5 don't well know each other...

Comment: This will have very little to do with Python itself. Unless you'd like to downgrade your Python version to use, I would drop the eric5 or PyQt people a line with your problem. I just noticed you used a binary installer for the Python 3.3 + Qt5 + PyQt4 combo, so since that didn't work, it's the PyQt developers that may have made a mistake somewhere (PyQt4 + Qt5 seems weird, since there is a PyQt5 out).